# Pound sign is higher then input fields in firefox?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

Here is my html form:

```
<form novalidate class="simple-form">
    <label>Reviews Min: <input type="number" ng-init="revNum=0" class="form-control review-input" min="0" step="10" ng-model="revNum" /></label>
    &#163;<label> Min Price: <input type="number" ng-init="minNum=0" class="form-control price-input" min="0" step="1000" ng-model="minNum" /></label>
    &#163;<label> Max Price: <input type="number" ng-init="maxNum=0" class="form-control price-input" min="0" step="1000" ng-model="maxNum" /></label>
    <label>&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-primary " style="display:block;" ng-click="updateNumArray(revNum, minNum, maxNum); updateActiveRow()">Filter</button></label>
                </form>
```

And here my css

```
.simple-form label{
    margin-right: 10px !important;
}

.simple-form button{
    background-color: #31708f;  
}

.price-input {
    width: 150px !important;
}
.review-input{
    width: 100px !important;
}
```

Here is an output in chrome:

[image]

and here in firefox:

[image]

As you can see the pound sign is higher then input fields in firefox.

How can I fix that.

Comment: Please share full CSS related to this Form!

Comment: Because with the code you have shared, there is no problem in any browser!!! Checkout this fiddle > http://jsfiddle.net/pgcagx3L/

Comment: well fiddle without twitter-bootstrap

Comment: You have not mentioned anywhere its using twitter-bootstrap!! It would be nice if you can create a fiddle with your code, which shows the bug you are getting.

Comment: @UID: I did. In my tags you can see `twitter-bootstrap`, and `btn btn-primary form-control` are bootstrap classes.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem I suggest you to use the code i made on this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1238/)

Simply wrapped the pound symbol with `span` tag and added some properties to fix the issue. Now it works in Chrome and FF.

Added CSS below:

```
.pound {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```